# Do I need to upgrade MATE 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

I am currently running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on an ASUS x550A and recently read 18.10 has reached EOL, does this mean I need to upgrade and if so to what do I upgrade?
I ran Software Upgrader and the System Monitor > System tab still shows 18.04.2

Any help and advice will be really appreciated as I am very much the novice.
Hal.

Comment: As you are using 18.04 LTS - then you should not worry until 2021. It is supported, see answer below, https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL .

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt replies and your time in answering my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS release has plenty of life left.

Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS is a long-term-support release, with 3 years of support starting with it's release in April 2018 (releases a *yy.mm* in format), so your support ends in April 2021.

The main Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has five years, but flavors come with 3 years of support.  Only the first (April) release in a even year is LTS (ie. 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS), the normal releases have shorter 9 months of support life.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes

> The 'main' archive of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years
>   until April 2023. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years for
>   Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, and Ubuntu Core. Ubuntu Studio 18.04
>   will be supported for 9 months. All other flavors will be supported
>   for 3 years.